# Existe alguma função que altera o background de uma activity no android studio?

Tags: java, android

Existe alguma maneira de criar uma função que altera o background de uma activity?

Preciso de um botão que ao clicar vai alterar o background da activity

Answer (score 0):

Você pode alterar o background do layout que ocupa toda a Activity com o método setBackgroundColor().

Por exemplo:

Seu XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout-width="match_parent"
    android:layout-height="match_parent">
   ...
</FrameLayout>
```

Sua Activity:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById (R.id.root_layout);
rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```